# Change woocommerce messages container position

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Because of my own little theme I have a problem with woocommerce. Normaly the container for the messages is before the `site-main` in woocommerce but it need to be in there.

How it actually looks like:

[image]

Because of massive problems it needs to be the first element in the DOM after the `site-main` class:

[image]

I've moved it in firefox that you know whats the problem. Is there anybody who know someting about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: @Aviator I'm using the Storefront theme